# How to test that a URL is called (from inside another thread)

Tags: python, mocking, python-requests

I have a simple thread comparing a counter to a limit and calling an URL when the counter is over the limit.

I would like to unit test this thread to assert that the URL is called when the value is over the limit.

How could this be done ? I have looked at requests-mock but it seems to work only when the requests comes from the current code block.

Code to test :

```
class SimpleCounter(threading.Thread):
    # Omitted ctor & other methods for brevity
    def run(self):
        limit = 5
        while not self.must_stop:
            if self.value > limit:
                requests.get("http://localhost/alarm.cgi")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Test code :

```
def test_simplecounterapp():
    counter = SimpleCounter()
    counter.start()
    for i in range(6):
        counter.increment()
    # assert http://localhost/alarm.cgi is indeed called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I have solved the issue by mocking urllib2.urlopen and asserting that the mock was called.